# C# does removing an object from a List clear event handlers

Tags: c#, memory, .net-core, signalr

I have a .NET Core backend with SignalR that accepts client connections.
On every connection a so called "scheduler" is created and stored in a Dictionary. Once a connection is closed this scheduler object is removed from the list.

Now, for these scheduler objects I set some CollectionChanged handlers for object properties like this:

```
...
scheduler.Grades.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => this.GradesListener(s, e, connectionId);
scheduler.Raws.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => this.MaterialsListener(s, e, connectionId);
scheduler.Heats.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => this.HeatsListener(s, e, connectionId);
...
```

Because there is a memory leak in the application my question is: If I remove the scheduler from the Dictionary (I do this with `Dictionary.Remove(key)`), are the event listeners removed as well? I would think so because the properties (Grades, Raws, Heats...) will be deleted as well, right?

If the handlers are not automatically removed, how would I "unregister" them?

Let me know if I need to provide more code.

I'm sorry if a question like this was asked before, I just couldn't find an answer.

Comment: To prevent resource leaks, after subscribing the event and doing his job you should unsubscribe them with " -=", like this: scheduler.Grades.CollectionChanged -= (s, e) => this.GradesListener(s, e, connectionId)

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Are you talking about the SignalR connection? I removed the scheduler from the Dictionary inside the `OnDisconnectedAsync` method and then called `await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);`. Is this not enaugh to stop the signalR connection?

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak? How do you know it is event handlers? Unless you've analysed your application's memory - which will tell you exactly what is being allocated - you are shooting in the dark.

Comment: @IanKemp I know because adding the scheduler to the list and creating event handlers are the only thing I do when a connection is esthablished. I took a look at the memory diagram and every connection permamently adds a couple of MB onto the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right,
After you remove entries from Grades, Raws and Heats, 
the GC will clean memory fine.

The problem is until you remove them `this` instance can't be cleaned.

You can find more information how to avoid memory leaks [here](https://michaelscodingspot.com/5-techniques-to-avoid-memory-leaks-by-events-in-c-net-you-should-know/).